# Globstar is enabled, and the pattern `**/` returns files only inside sub-directories but `**/*` returns files both in root and in sub-directories

Tags: bash, wildcard, glob, ls, shopt

My file structure looks like this

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 athar 197609 12467 Jun 12 22:33 rootFile1.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 athar 197609   736 Jun  9 17:42 rootFile2.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 athar 197609   662 Jun  9 18:21 rootFile3.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 athar 197609     0 Jun 15 23:58 testfolder/
```

with the `testfolder/` containing

```
testfolder:
subDirFile1.md  subDirFile2.md
```

I've enabled globstar using `shopt -s globstar`. The documentation of globstar states ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html))

If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match.

```
$ ls **/
subDirFile1.md  subDirFile2.md
```

This makes sense according to the docs, where it only matches dirs and sub-dirs, not files. However,

```
$ ls **/*.md
rootFile1.md  rootFile3.md               testfolder/subDirFile2.md
rootFile2.md  testfolder/subDirFile1.md
```

Shouldn't the above command only output the subDirFiles since `**` is followed by `/` and as per docs, only directories and subdirectories match? Why does it match files in the root as well?

I should also mention that when i disable globstar, the output will only search the sub directory.

```
$ ls **/*.md
testfolder/subDirFile1.md  testfolder/subDirFile2.md
```

Comment: To see clearly the effect of expansion, use `echo` instead of `ls`, like `echo **/*.md`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think part of the confusion here is that `ls` itself also implicitly expands directories -- that is, if you pass a directory name as an argument, it lists the *contents* of the directory rather than the directory itself. This means the output from something like `ls **/` is the result of two expansion processes, each of which plays by different rules.

You can see this clearly with `set -x`, which makes bash print each command *after* substitutions and expansions have been done:

```
$ ls **/
+ ls testfolder/
subDirFile1.md  subDirFile2.md
```

Here, the `**/` expands to just the directory that's in the current directory. It does not include the current directory, which is why rootFile1.md etc are not listed.

It *would* include subdirectories if there were any. Let's create one and see the effect:

```
$ mkdir testfolder/subdir
+ mkdir testfolder/subdir
$ touch testfolder/subdir/subsubfile{1..2}.md
+ touch testfolder/subdir/subsubfile1.md testfolder/subdir/subsubfile2.md

$ ls **/
+ ls testfolder/ testfolder/subdir/
testfolder/:
subDirFile1.md  subDirFile2.md  subdir

testfolder/subdir/:
subsubfile1.md  subsubfile2.md
```

Now `ls` got two directories as arguments, so it breaks the listing into sections by directory, making it clearer what's going on.

Another way to help clarify this is to use `ls -d`, which tells `ls` *not* to implicitly expand directories, so you only see one level of expansion happening.

Answer (score 1):

From `man bash`:

> When the globstar shell option is enabled, [..] two adjacent `*`s used as a single pattern will match all files and **zero** or more directories and subdirectories.

Your `rootFile1.md` does indeed have zero directories in front, so it matches.

Comment: What about "If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match." that's mentioned in the doc? Wouldn't that exclude `rootFile1.md` from being matched?

Comment: The way it's written in the manual is sort of confusing, the `**/` part only matches zero or more directories and subdirectories but the `*.md` part can match on regular files.

Comment: If your goal is to ignore the root directory then the correct pattern should be `*/**/*.md`

Answer (score 0):

To officially expand on the existing answer, when globstar is enabled:

- `**` matches "all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories"
- `**/` will not match files on its own, but otherwise it behaves the same as `**` meaning it CAN match zero directories/subdirectories.
- `*.md` is a plain old glob and can match on anything.

When you put it all together, `**/*.md` says "match in zero or more directories/subdirectories something ending in .md." Your root directory is zero directories deep, so it's included in the match.

For completeness, when globstar is disabled `**` is equivalent to `*` so `ls **/*.md` is the same thing as `ls */*.md`.

If your goal is to ignore the root directory, you can prepend the pattern with `*/` to create `*/**/*.md`. The leading `*/` will only match directories and doesn't have the same gotcha of matching on "zero directories".